# Van Kampen theorem on n-manifold remove one point

Tags: manifolds, fundamental-groups

I'm trying to prove for a ($n \geq 3$)-dimensional path connected manifold M, if remove a point in M, then use Van Kampen theorem can somehow show the fundamental group of original $M$ and $M-{x}$, and $M-U_x$ where $U_x$ is the open neighbourhood of $x$ are the same.

I know the open neighbourhood $U_x$ is homeomorphic to open n-ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I can feel it is true as then intersect $U_x$ with $(M-{x})$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$. But I just cannot get my head around with all the details and how the logic actually goes.

Can anybody please try to help me in details? I really wish to understand the details in between as I do have rough intuition, it is details missing here.

Also, what is a good counter example for $n=2$?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: You do not need Seifert - Van Kampen's theorem to solve this problem. Instead, try the definition of fundamental group in conjunction with Sard's theorem and approximation of continuous maps by smooth ones.

Answer (score 2):

Let $U=M-x$, $V=U_x$, then $M=U \cup V \cong R^n$, $U \cap V \cong S^{n-1}$ 
Then use Van Kampen's theorem. Actually since $\pi_1(S^{n-1})=0$, that normal subgroup $N$ must be $0$. So  $\pi_1(M)=\pi_1(U)$.

Similarly $\pi(M)=\pi(M-U_x)$. Just let $V$ be a larger ball.

For n=2. The problem is $\pi_1(S^{1})=\mathbb{Z}$. Think about the torus.
The fundamental group of torus minus one point is $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How do you know that U is simplyconnected, without using the approximation theorem?

Comment: This is proposition 1.14 in Hatcher's book. @studiosus