# Calculating the fundamental group of $X \setminus \mathbb S^1$, for $n\ge 3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

1. $X = \mathbb S^n$

I think I got this one very roughly. Since we had that $\mathbb S^n\setminus\{N\}\cong\mathbb R^n$ by stereographic projection, we can suppose that $N$ is sent to the point of infinity in $\mathbb R^n$ and say that $\mathbb S^n\setminus\mathbb S^1\cong \mathbb R^n\setminus\{$straight line$\}(\cong\mathbb R^n\setminus\{$axis$\})$. Since $\Pi_1(\mathbb R^n\setminus\{$axis$\})\cong \Pi_1(\mathbb S^{n-2})$ (all of this has been proved beforehand, I just don't want to make my proof any longer), we have that
\begin{equation*}
\Pi_1(\mathbb S^n\setminus\mathbb S^1) =
\begin{cases}
\mathbb Z & \quad \text{if $n=3$} \\
\{0\} & \quad \text{if $n>3$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
The different cases rub me the wrong way, so I don't know whether it is correct or not.

2. X = $\mathbb R^n$

In page 46 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, we see an example of an application of Seifert-Van Kampen Theorem where they get the fundamental group of $\mathbb R^3\setminus\mathbb S^1$, which is $\mathbb Z$. In this case I haven't finished the proof, since I have no idea how to move on from here. Maybe $\mathbb R^n\setminus\mathbb S^1$ is homotopic to $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{$straight line$\}$, and we get the same result as before? Or maybe we get that it deformation retracts to $\mathbb S^{n-1}\vee \mathbb S^1$ (or is homotopic, at the very least).

Could anyone, please, help me out?

Comment: Your computation for 1) is correct. The intuitive reason you get something non-trivial when $n=3$ is basically "because knots exist." I think you get something similar any time you look at the complement of $\mathbb S^{n-2}$ inside of $\mathbb S^n$.

Comment: How is $S^1$ embedded into $X$? An arbitrary embedding or something special?

Comment: They are in the description. My apologies for not making it clear enough.

Comment: This is probably the type of thing that you are looking for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775109/van-kampen-theorem-on-n-manifold-remove-one-point

Comment: Oh, so that result gets me to check, for instance, which is the fundamental group of $\mathbb R^n\setminus(\mathbb S^1\cup\{p\})$, for $p\not\in\mathbb S^1$?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the answer to the 2nd case.

If we reason similarly to the 1st case, we have that if we have that $\mathbb R^n\cong \mathbb S^n\setminus\{N\}$, and locate $N\in\mathbb S^1$, then we have that $\mathbb R^n\setminus \mathbb S^1 \cong \mathbb S^n\setminus\mathbb S^1 (*)$, hence $\Pi_1(\mathbb R^n\setminus \mathbb S^1) \cong \Pi_1(\mathbb S^n\setminus\mathbb S^1)$. We computed in 1. the latter fundamental group, so by the isomorphism,
\begin{equation*}
\Pi_1(\mathbb R^n\setminus\mathbb S^1) = 
\begin{cases}
\mathbb Z & \quad \text{if $n=3$} \\
\{0\} & \quad \text{if $n>3$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I don't know if $(*)$ is very precise. Is this answer correct?

P.S.: Thanks to Tabes Bridges for confirming that 1. was correct.

Comment: If $N \in S^1$, then $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus S^1$ doesn't really make sense since $N \notin \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @JHF I wrote it very roughly, so maybe I didn't explain myself properly. I'm taking a point $p$ of $\mathbb S^n$ that also belongs to $\mathbb S^1$. In this case, $p\in\mathbb R^n$, since $\mathbb S^1\subset\mathbb R^n$. Perhaps the notation with $N$ confused you, my apologies.

Comment: In fact, it was my bad for trying to simplify the proof. I wanted to skip a step where I would have to show that $\mathbb S^n\setminus\{p\}\cong\mathbb S^n\setminus\{N\}$, and then we would have that $\mathbb S^n\setminus\{N\}\cong\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: In any case, it is not true that $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus S^1 \simeq  S^n \setminus S^1$ (with the standard embedding of $S^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: I see. Off to try something else.